# Communicating with a running process from shell

Tags: linux, shell, sockets, ipc, pid

I am running a large computation application in a linux environment. my goal is to create a interface that can communicate with the application from a shell window and get results from application and print it in the shell.

Lets say i have a application that writes prime numbers infinitely to a file. After certain time, if you wanna know what the application doing, is it possible to create a interface like,

```
$[ pid ] "Display current number in check";
$The number, 17559323 is currently checked if its a prime.
```

It is deliberate that i had a "$" in prompt as it should be possible for a normal user to communicate. signals needs privileged execution. As i may have many instances of this application running i dunno how sockets can actually help as i would want to talk specifically to that process for getting the status.
Any direction on communicating with a running process from shell will be highly helpful.

Comment: You could have your application listen on a socket for commands.  A client program could connect to that socket, send commands, read responses, and display them to the user.  If you have multiple instances of the application running, just have each one open a socket (maybe name them after the PID or something).

Comment: This do not give me the client-less interface i am looking for. also it needs to have a small client application floated around for my peers to communicate with the application. Meaning the toolset is not self contained.  (Nor supported by os tools like bash stdin/out )

Comment: So instead of a socket, make it an embedded http server.  Now you can query it with `curl`.

Comment: @larsks .. This is an interesting idea i will surely remember this trick. But in this case i will have to manage port number issues.First to figure out a mechanism of how to make this application to tell the port number to outside world(may b by a small log file ) and  if i run multiple instances, this do not seem like a viable solution to pick an unused port number at runtime and communicate it to the user. but nevertheless it somehow solves the purpose. Thanks. i will keep looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use logs: client can *grep* (or *tail*) this logs to see what is happening now. You can write to log file always or make a signal handler that will dump required information to file after receiving a signal.

Comment: This do not answer any part of the question of communication with a running process via shell. For a running process , to write such a log is 1. very inefficient if no one polls for status for that instance execution, 2. It will slow the application because of harddisk r/w cycles and 3. will only dump the space. The main purpose is Information Poling and not documentation of a execution.